# Routing of a public IP network

Tags: networking, ip, routing, subnet

Given a (public) network 198.51.100.0/24 that is routed to HostA and I want to route a subnet of it (say, 198.51.100.16/28) to HostB. HostA and HostB are connected over some sort of point-to-point link (e.g. VPN or PPP).

What are the options (and what is the best practice) to route such a net? Technically I should not use a private IP (RFC1918) because such an IP should never be mixed with publicly routable IP addresses.

I could split off a /30 network and use it as a point-to-point link between HostA and HostB and on top of it route 198.51.100.16/28. But that seems wasteful.

Can I use a RFC1918 address for it? Can I use a link-local address?

Edit: I tried tracert and indeed, there are RFC1918 addresses interspersed in between (Note: the first one I think is my CGNAT but the others are definitely in the public network):

```
  [...]
  2    70 ms    70 ms    71 ms  10.8.0.1
  3    78 ms    71 ms    73 ms  D [64.44.32.1]
  4    72 ms    71 ms    71 ms  89-88-12-198.as20278.net [198.12.88.89]
  5    72 ms    74 ms    70 ms  10.8.40.245
  6    71 ms    71 ms    73 ms  10.8.6.33
  7    75 ms    71 ms    73 ms  buf-b1-link.ip.twelve99.net [62.115.59.89]
  8    82 ms     *       81 ms  nyk-bb1-link.ip.twelve99.net [62.115.118.122]
  9   188 ms     *      157 ms  ldn-bb4-link.ip.twelve99.net [62.115.112.245]
 10   364 ms   212 ms   294 ms  prs-bb2-link.ip.twelve99.net [62.115.114.229]
 11   208 ms   297 ms   304 ms  ffm-bb2-link.ip.twelve99.net [62.115.122.139]
 12   282 ms   246 ms   361 ms  win-bb4-link.ip.twelve99.net [62.115.138.23]
 13   303 ms   180 ms   325 ms  win-b2-link.ip.twelve99.net [62.115.114.183]
[...]
```

Comment: You can't use a link-local address, because they are not routable. I don't see what could go wrong with an RFC1918 address - the two P2P addresses shouldn't leak.

Comment: +1 to @dirkt comment - RFC1918 is absolutely fine to use across a VPN or PPP link - You may be confusing this with leaking RFC1918 space onto the wider Internet or accepting RFC1918 traffic from the the wider Internet, but the inside of your VPN/PPP connection is part of your network.

Comment: @dirkt: The gateway addresses themselves don't always have to be "routable"; link-local for point-to-point links is fairly common in practice, even for IPv4 (though less so). Though it _could_ cause problems with routing protocols, I guess, but for static routes it would be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Even if I route a **public network** over it? Traceroute would technically need to show the RFC1918 IP then, no? Also, why does link local not work? The link local addresses would not need to be routed, they would just constitute the "transfer network" (point to point link).

Comment: On the other hand, @divB's "Technically I should not use a private IP (RFC1918) because such an IP should never be mixed with publicly routable IP addresses" also sounds weird to me. Where did this "rule" come from? There's _really_ no problem mixing the two.

Comment: @divB: Ah, you're right about traceroute and other ICMP errors. But that can be avoided, if the gateway itself is somehow told to use a specific source IP address, e.g. in Linux, if all routes have 'prefsrc' set, then that address will be used in traceroute responses. (And in practice, I've seen plenty of RFC1918 responses in traceroutes ... _even in IPv6 traceroutes._)

Comment: I just tried tracert to my own address from the internet and indeed, there are a few 10.0.0.0/8 IPs interspersed in between. Is it correct then that large datacenters/exchanges use those too to connect different public networks? Is this "good" practice? Do I need to take care of anything when doing this?

Comment: @user1686 I remember trying to set up static routing via link-local IPv4 addresses on Linux, and it not working. Though I forgot the details, and of course it could have been my mistake. I also have never seen link-local autoconfigured addresses on point-to-point links, though again that could be me.

Comment: "I just tried tracert to my own address from the internet and indeed, there are a few 10.0.0.0/8 IPs interspersed in between." That sounds very wrong - private IP addresses shouldn't be visible from the outside. But many ISPs use private IP ranges in their own network, including the customer that is part of that network.

Comment: @dirkt Why? Either it's "allowed" that RF1819 addresses are used for transit networks, then they should show up in tracert or they are not allowed. I updated my post withe the tracert output where the 10/8 networks are clearly visible.

Comment: `64.44.32.1` is owned by NordVPN, so I'd assume you are using a VPN connection, you get assigned a private IP inside NordVPN, and there are some "routable" IPs thrown in until you reach the edge of NordVPN at 10.8.6.33, where it would do NAT and go into the public internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any subnet from the RFC 1918 ranges for routing in between. As long as the connected hosts can make sense of it it'll work. For a P2P link, a /31 subnet is sufficient. For a PPP connection, addressing isn't even required, just routing.

Just make sure that no private IP packets leak out from any host to the Internet. Especially HostB needs to use 198.51.100.16/28 address for outgoing packets to the Internet - usually that can be established by binding all relevant services specifically to that address.

However, routing from the 198.51.100.0/24 to the 198.51.100.16/28 subnet may pose a challenge as they overlap. Hosts on 198.51.100.0/24 will not use HostA as gateway. You'll need to use static ARP entries, proxy ARP or similar to get the packets routed. It might be useful to cleanly subnet 198.51.100.0/24 first, making the problem trivial.

`tracert` works by sending incremental TTL probes towards the destination and displaying where they timed out. As long as intermediate gateways return a *TTL expired in transit* message you'll see them in the list. Whether they use public or private addresses on the used interface or just as a general ICMP source address doesn't matter.

If you don't want that you need to either disable or filter such messages (making the hop show up as `* * *`) or use a public IP address for ICMP errors. Note that HostA is the last hop gateway, so it depends on its setup (likely a public address anyway). HostB won't time out the TTL because that is only checked when forwarding - HostB might reply to a `ping` though but that usually returns the ping's destination address (which cannot be private from the public Internet).

Comment: Finally a great answer to this, thanks! Could you maybe just elaborate on the trace route question? Will the private IPs show up in a trace route? (If yes, is it a problem, if not, why not?)

Comment: Another remark: yes, my goal would be to first cleanly subnet 198.51.100.0/24. Is the reason why it’s getting “trivial” because each interface has a different network? What if the whole /24 is announced; would there be any issues with the subnetting?

Comment: I've added an answer to tracert as well. Clean subnetting means no overlapping subnets and unambiguous routing. Overlapping subnets can be somewhat get to work using route metrics and perhaps static ARP entries but that is more a hack than a setup - and it's likely to land on your feet some day.